# Move ASP.NET test Startup class outside of project root directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor (ASP.NET Core 3.0) application (the default template) and I want to write some integration tests using Selenium. For this, I need to launch the web application before the tests run.

I do this by running

```
CreateHostBuilderWithStartup<Startup>(new string[0]).UseContentRoot(contentRoot).Build().RunAsync();

private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilderWithStartup<TStartup>(string[] args) where TStartup : class
    {
        return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<TStartup>();
            });
    }
```

where `contentRoot` is the path to the project under test. This works fine, the server runs as expected.

My solution contains 2 projects - The application code and the test code.

However, if I try to use a Startup class from the test project which inherits from startup (i.e. `CreateHostBuilderWithStartup<TestStartup>`) then the server returns a 500 internal server error for every request. The error in the console output for the server is:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: Error: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.

System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /_Host, area:  }.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.DynamicPageEndpointMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|6_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>g__Awaited|6_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddleware middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App\3.0.0-preview6.19307.2\Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
```

If I move the TestStartup into the main code project, this works fine, but ideally I want to keep the test code in the test project. I need to use this TestStartup class so that I can override the ConfigureServices method to change the injected dependencies.

**So the core of this question is, can I have the Startup class outside of the root directory of the ASP.NET Core project that I am running?**

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Probably you need to use [ApplicationParts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-2.2)? Not that I have done this yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a lot of experimenting and research, it seems it is currently not possible to move the Startup class, due to a bug with it not respecting the `ContentRoot` path set using the `UseContentRoot` method. This bug is tracked by [issue #11921](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/11921) on AspNetCore GitHub.

A very hacky workaround if you need to be able to inject dependencies from a test project, is to create a static class `Dependencies` in your main project, with a static `Action<IStartupConfiguration> RegisterDependencies` field, which you then call in the Startup class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    Dependencies.RegisterDependencies(services);
}
```

Then, in `Program.cs` set `RegisterDepenedencies` to register the dependencies you need:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dependencies.RegisterDependencies = s =>
    {
        s.AddSingleton<IWeatherForecastService, WeatherForecastService>();
    };

    CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
}
```

You can now change this method in the test project to configure different dependencies when running integration tests. In your test project:

```
Dependencies.RegisterDependencies = s =>
{
    s.AddSingleton<IWeatherForecastService, MockWeatherForecastService>();
};
```

**This is very hacky, hopefully the `ContentRoot` issue is fixed, then changing the content root to the main project should be used instead**

Comment: might be a silly question but why haven't you been using like so: `Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0]).Build().RunAsync();` works at least for me. I got both projects binded together by a `.sln` file. Am I missing any details why this is not working for your case? Where program is from my blazor server.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked:

```cs
Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0]).Build().RunAsync();
```

while I had to create a `.sln` which binds the project with the test folder like shown in [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit)